# Making React-Modal Non transparent

Tags: css, reactjs, react-modal

[image][image]I am using react-modal in my code.
Please find below its style,

```
const customStyles = {
    content : {
      top                   : '37%',
      left                  : '50%',
      right                 : 'auto',
      bottom                : 'auto',
      marginRight           : '-50%',
      transform             : 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
      maxWidth              : '40%'
    }
  };
```

When I click any row from my grid, modal pops up. But the issue is, when I click row, row gets highlighted and it shows up in front of modal.
I do not want highlighted row or grid to distract Modal view.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure the modal is transparent? sounds like a zIndex issue?

Comment: I have added image in question, you can see in picture that row is highlighted over modal. Also some header components.

Comment: 100% looks like a z-index issue to me. try bumping the z-index  of the modal

Comment: I tried z-index:1000, but no luck

Comment: how did you try it?

Comment: also, don't just try a random number. make sure it's higher than the zindex of the selected row

Comment: I added zIndex to customstyles (in question), zIndex : 1000

Comment: but no `zIndex` ?

Comment: can you take a screenshot of the elements panel to make sure its getting applied properly?

Comment: I added screenshot in question. It is getting applied correctly